# How to blacklist additional HTML tags in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I really dislike the non-semantic usage of `<big>` on our wiki, and would like to prevent it. Flat-out commands didn't work so far, so I'm switching to doing it by code...

AFAIK, there's no configuration switch to control the blacklist/whitelist of HTML tags. Looking at the source code, it seems like the data is coming from `Sanitizer::getRecognizedTagData()`, while the work itself is done in `Sanitizer::removeHTMLtags()`. However, I do not see a way to add to the list myself, except using one of the hooks before or after (`InternalParseBeforeSanitize`, `InternalParseBeforeLinks`) and either:

1. Call `Sanitizer::removeHTMLtags()` again myself, with the additional tag to blacklist as a parameter
2. Do a search myself on the text to remove all the `<big>` tags.

The first one is a duplication of work, the second one is a duplication of code. Is there a better way? What would you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No coding is needed: just install [AbuseFilter](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AbuseFilter) and create a rule that warns or disallows on save of pages containing these tags.